# database settings in reactioncommerce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I installed [reactioncommerce](http://reactioncommerce.com) and I would like to access the database settings to check the name that the installation created in my mongodb server. I checked the information on the website but I cannot find any details about it.

in mongodb: when I use "show dbs" in mongo I cannot see any new db in my server. on the other hand, the demo application is running on port localhost:3000.

any guidance appreciated.

Comment: How are you accessing mongodb? Open up a new terminal, go to your app directory and type: `meteor mongo` - this will open a console into your app's local development database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well it seems the mongodb for meteor always runs at one port above the meteor port. So by default the db is running at 3001. While you can have Meteor running you can also run meteor mongo and get a db console that way.